# How do I get my Raspberry Pi to get data from my Parallax RFID reader

Tags: rfid

I have a Raspberry Pi model B+ 
I'm trying to read RFID tags using the Parallax RFID reader. 
I've downloaded the python gpio tools, as well as libnfc.
When I run nfc-list, it says no devices found.

[image]

When I run minicom, nothing is read. What should I do to find the problem?

Comment: I got it. I had to connect the VCC to the 5V and disconnect from the 3V.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution.  Could you please post your solution as an answer and then self accept it please?

Answer (score 1):

The Parallax RFID Reader needs an input voltage of 5V.
This connects to the VCC.
It is enabled by connecting the enable line to a pin with 0 bit value.
The RFID reader needs to be level shifted, from 5V to 3V. 
Following this guide, http://www.instructables.com/id/Pi-Cubed-How-to-connect-a-33V-Raspberry-Pi-to-a-5V/ I connected in series, the output from the RFID reader (SOUT) to 2 100 ohm resistors, and then connected that to RXD0 on the breadboard. 
RXD0 corresponds with GPIO 15 on the Raspberry Pi.
I was then able to read data from the serial port.

Still no luck with nfc-list